# Shortest path in a schedule network (Constraint on Arc)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, visual-c++, shortest

How can I enumerate all k-shortest path?

I've read that we may use Depth-first-algorithm, but how we track the index and position of the arcs in the path list?

Note that each connected node has a parallel arc.

The other question is What the best way to save all path from all s-t nodes? Note that we don’t know the number of paths and the size of each path.

I am attempting to find all paths from a single node to a single destination in a scheduled service on Arc.

I follow one paper in which they propose a k-shortest path in a schedule network.

Comment: 'arc' as in edge? Out of all the paths from source vertex to destination vertex you want the k shortest ones?

Comment: yes arc is as edge. the issue is that the network is schedule and in compacted when means there is parallel arc